# Symfony3 Save two related enitites into DB

Tags: doctrine, symfony-3.4

I try to save Customer and Contact entities in one form. 
My Customer Entity fields:

```
Id 
Name
LastName
ContactId
```

<- This have relation OneToOne with `Id` field in Contact Entity.

My Contact Entity fields:

```
Id
Phone
Address
```

I try do one form and save this entities to DB. 
How to do that? 
Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your Entities are well done, you just have to set your Contact to your Customer and save the Customer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you include your annotations (or yml/xml) so we can better understand how you've implemented the OneToOne association?